# How to trait 1,64Million of records on MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, memory-management, bigdata

I have a hug amount of data on MongoDB I want to compare them but the process needs some logical side to achieve the goal, I know that using Java for the case seems to be complicated for Memory usages?

USA CASE :

I want to compare two documents "Tables" in mongodb that has a large amount of data >1.46M lines, we need to use an approach or some logical part which allows us to do it efficiently without losing memory capacities or arrived to the worth cases ?

I've tried to put the data into java collections and in order to get the descripancies between them, I implement the comparison logic code side using threads but i got a lot of memory leaks and the process takes a lot of time.

Comment: You must add a lot of more details for this question to be answerable.

Comment: the question is clear , but i added some more details to be comprehensive. thank you